# ulimit doesn't take effect on core file size?

Tags: c++, linux, bash

Tried to limit core dump file size. I want to limit to be about 4MB, so I set it to be 1000 (blocks,  each block is 4KB).  But it doesn't limit the core dump file size. Any ideas?

```
$ ulimit -c
1000
$ rm core; ./a.out
start...
Floating point exception (core dumped)
$ ls -l core
-rw------- 1 jin1 jin1 100405248 Nov 21 09:22 core
```

The a.out was produced by a simple C++ source. Don't think it matters though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

void baz() {
 int a = 0;
  printf("%d\n", 1/a);       // causes segfault
}

void bar() { baz(); }
void foo() { bar(); }

char buf[100000000];
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int i=0; i<100000000; i++) 
        buf[i] = 'a';
    printf("start...\n");
    foo();
    printf("%c\n", buf[100]);
}
```

**Update 2**

Update the snippet with setrlimit and getrlimit, now I don't get a core file. Wonder why.  Here is quick run:

```
$ g++ te2.cc
$ ./a.out
start with limit: 1000 1000
Floating point exception (core dumped)
$ ls -l core
ls: cannot access core: No such file or directory
$ ulimit -c
1000
```

Here is the new source for te2.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sys/resource.h>

void baz() {
 int a = 0;
  printf("%d\n", 1/a);       // causes segfault
}

void bar() { baz(); }
void foo() { bar(); }

char buf[50000000];
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int i=0; i<50000000; i++) 
        buf[i] = 'a';
    struct rlimit n= {1000, 1000};
    struct rlimit v = {0,0};
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &n);
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &v);
    printf("start with limit: %ld %ld\n", v.rlim_cur, v.rlim_max);
    foo();
    printf("%c\n", buf[100]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ask, yes I did. That's why I ran it as `rm core; ./a.out`. I checked the timestamp of the core dump file, it's new.

Comment: What happens if you lower size of buffer used in your code?

Comment: When I set the buffer to be 50MB (instead of 100MB), the core dump file is about 50MB. In another word, the buffer takes majority of the core dump file.  I actually just need the stacktrack dump to be in the core, don't care about memory.

Comment: Could you run blockdev --getbsz <partition> to show your block size?

Comment: Thanks @user3545806 for asking,  it's 4000: `# blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda1
4096
`

Comment: I would suggest to do exec from inside the binary with ulimit -c and check that it is still 1000.

Comment: @user3545806, `exec`?! Why not just `setrlimit()`??

Comment: @Alexis Wilke yes, that is way better. getrlimit() and see what it says,

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Mint 17.2 64bit I used ulimit -c 1000 and ran ulimit -a to confirm the value was set and ran your sample.  I am getting a core of :
 1024000 Nov 21 10:43 core


Run ulimit -a before running your code to insure your settings are there.


There is also an option to run ulimit -Sc 1000 or ulimit -Hc 1000 for soft or hard settings.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting checking "ulimit -a",  yes it confirms the limit is set: `core file size          (blocks, -c) 1000`

Comment: What version/distro of Linux are you running?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. Thanks.